# How to drop a specific Django table which uses PostgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I want to delete a Django UserModel table and then recreate it.

Or delete user field and recreate it with a new user by `python manage.py createsuperuser`

---

[**NOTE**]:

My DB is PostgreSQL on a docker container.

Comment: run this comand in your terminal  `docker run image_name sh -c "python manage.py dbshell"`. After that you will be able to run SQL comands. Then run `DROP TABLE appname_modelname;`

Comment: it throw this error: command error: you appear not to have the psql program installed or on your path

Comment: You need to be CAREFUL. If you have other models related to django user model with foreign key relation and if you pass cascade option in your sql than the other tables might be dropped. It's also valid in delete statements. You might end up losing data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to delete a development database (e.g., during local development?).

In that case, I usually like to just unapply and reapply migrations, making any changes to migrations I need before reapplying them.

E.g.,:

```
$ python manage.py migrate auth zero
$ python manage.py migrate auth
```

This would destroy the auth tables ([Permission, Group, and User](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0001_initial.py)) and recreate them without any data.

If you have other migrations that depend on auth, they will have been rolled back too. In that case you can just migrate the whole app back with:

```sh
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I'm dealing with this error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: table "app_name_userreportmodel" does not exist`

Comment: I'm guessing that `UserReportModel` depends on one of the auth models and was rolled back as well. Just run `python manage.py migrate` to migrate your whole app back to the state described by your current migrations.

Answer (score 0):

connect to psql or using pgAdmin
connect to your databese
execute the query:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  CASCADE;